# Excel – как автоматически делать группировку «плюсиком»?

Tags: excel

Есть шаблон страницы в экселе, куда добавляются данные.

В первом столбце данные идут с инкрементом, но между инкрементами могут быть «дубли», то есть

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
```

и т.д.

Мне нужно автоматически группировать все однотипные данные так, чтобы отображалось первое значение и по «плюсику» раскрывать все остальные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные могут добавляться и хочется, чтобы все срабатывало автоматически.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Только в VBA (макросом). И если с добавлением данных, код должен сначала разгруппировать все строки, потом отсортировать и только после этого гркуппировать.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Такая работа выходит за рамки обычной помощи. Есть желание - пишите на почту

Comment: Приятно знать, что все в этой жизни не бесплатно, но хочется узнать ответ на вопрос от людей, которые могут делиться знаниями не только за деньги на столь крупном проекте

Comment: Как Вы можете оценить время на работу, если не знаете предмета? Не крупная работа, но потребует времени, которое, как известно, не резиновое. Ждите, может, кому будет интересно потренироваться, размяться.